Elastic Search - dense vector search extremely slow
I am using elastic search to index ecommerce retail data to get similar products/match products, i am using openai CLIP to generate dense vectors from text/images but the queries are extremely slow, I am using Elastic Search 8
Here is how i create the dense vectors in the ES database
                   'image_vector' => [
                       'type' => 'dense_vector',
                       'dims' => 512,
                       'index' => true,
                       'similarity' => 'cosine',
                       "index_options"=> [
                              "type"=> "hnsw",
                              "m"=> 16,
                              "ef_construction"=> 100
                            ]
                   ],



                   'text_vector' => [
                       'type' => 'dense_vector',
                       'dims' => 512,
                       'index' => true,
                       'similarity' => 'cosine',
                         "index_options"=> [
                              "type"=> "hnsw",
                              "m"=> 16,
                              "ef_construction"=> 100
                            ]
                   ],

here is how i create the should conditions
                            $should[] = [
                            'script_score' => [
                                'query' => [
                                    'bool' => [
                                        'filter' => [
                                            // Only consider documents with image_vector
                                            ['exists' => ['field' => 'image_vector']]
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                ],
                                'script' => [
                                    'source' => "
                                        double similarity = doc['image_vector'].size() > 0 ? cosineSimilarity(params.query_vector, 'image_vector') : 0;
                                        return similarity > 0.5 ? (similarity + 1.0) * 1000.0 : 0;
                                    ",
                                    'params' => ['query_vector' => $vector['vector'][0]]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ];

                        // Add script_score for text_vector similarity
                        $should[] = [
                            'script_score' => [
                                'query' => [
                                    'bool' => [
                                        'filter' => [
                                            // Only consider documents with text_vector
                                            ['exists' => ['field' => 'text_vector']]
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                ],
                                'script' => [
                                    'source' => "
                                        double similarity = doc['text_vector'].size() > 0 ? cosineSimilarity(params.query_vector, 'text_vector') : 0;
                                        return similarity > 0.5 ? (similarity + 1.0) * 500.0 : 0;
                                    ",
                                    'params' => ['query_vector' => $vector['vector_text'][0]]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ];


                }


Elasticsearch supports two methods for kNN search:

Approximate kNN using the knn search option or knn query
Exact, brute-force kNN using a script_score query with a vector function
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/knn-search.html#knn-methods

Exact search is too expensive. Use kNN search instead.
I'm sharing an example kNN search below.
POST image-index/_search
{
  "knn": {
    "field": "image-vector",
    "query_vector": [-5, 9, -12],
    "k": 10,
    "num_candidates": 100
  },
  "fields": [ "title", "file-type" ]
}

You can read the following article for image search.
https://www.elastic.co/search-labs/blog/implement-image-similarity-search-elastic


can you please confirm that the mapping is correct for knn search? i tried knn search before posting here but i always get no results, i checked and the fields are there, are dense vector; also, i would need a way to add the knn search as $should[] = []; to the other conditions i have

I'm not sure if you are using 512 dimensions in your ML model but the mapping looks correct. index: true allows you to use kNN. Please check the examples in the links I shared with you. Create a test env without code and use Elasticsearch and Kibana DevTools for testing purpose. Also, use elastic cloud for testing and see the result. Go step by step.

i ran a simple knn search for its still extremely slow, almost as slow as the original code that used script source, anything else i can try?

what is the mean of slow? How did you measure the slow. Please elaborate more that I can help you more

a query in a table with around 60k documents, doing that search takes about 20-30 seconds sometimes, sometimes 4-5 seconds.

yes 20 second is too much, try to adjust num_candidates to fine tune the search latency
